# How to display JS slices in html <span>

Tags: javascript, html, slice

I need to figure out how to add these JS slices together and get them to display in an HTML textarea. The values, from a product configurator, of the slices change based on user selections, so is it possible for the textarea where they are displayed to automatically update when a different selection has changed one of the values?

The slices look like this:

```
skus[0].partSku, skus[1].partSku, skus[2].materialSku, skus[3].materialSku, skus[4].materialSku, skus[5].materialSku
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
    <span id="finalSku"></span>
    </div>
    <script>
    function getBOM() {
      var BOM = HAPPY.getBOM();
    }
    function getSKU()
    {
        var partsMaterials = skus[0].partSku() + skus[1].partSku() + skus[2].materialSku() + skus[3].materialSku() + skus[4].materialSku() + skus[5].materialSku();

        document.getElementById('finalSku').innerHTML =
                                          partsMaterials;

    }
    </script>
```

Ideally, I would love for the textarea to populate based on these 6 slices from a generated BOM and update if the values of any of these slices change.

I am more than willing to help clarify my needs if necessary.

Comment: Are we talking about `<select>`s? Because if so, all you need is an `onchange` listener that calls `getSKU()` again.

Comment: @Chris G, they are selects, I believe. I'm just not sure how to display the SKUs from above in an HTML div for the user to see.

Comment: But isn't that exactly what `getSKU` does? Or are you never calling it at all? Ideally you create a [mre] in the question showing what you've tried to far.

Comment: @Chris G, I might not be calling it. This is the culmination of trial and error, mostly. I feel like what is shown above should work, but it doesn't. I'm no JS whizkid, just stumbled into this deep dark forest.

Comment: The code you have in your question is definitely not calling anything, it's just declaring two functions. None of that code will ever run. And what is `HAPPY`? Can you create a [mre] that has example HTML, i.e. one or two `<select>` elements?

Comment: The SKU information is delivered via API in the BOM. I'm just trying to display the portions that I need.

This is how is comes:

Comment: skus: [{
        "group": "Side1 ",
        "material": "1 ",
        "part": "Medium",
        "sku": "-6P",
        "partSku": "-6",
        "materialSku": "P",
        "multiplier": 1
    }, {
        "group": "Side 1",
        "material": "1",
        "part": "Medium",
        "sku": "1-M-P",
        "partSku": "1-M-",
        "materialSku": "P",
        "multiplier": 1
    }, ]

Comment: @Chris G, thanks for the help. I guess I'm more lost than I thought I was.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/0h294zo6/ (and please don't put code in comments; add it to your question)